# can't execute cvs command in DOS in windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, cvs

When cvs is typed in cmd.exe in windows 7 nothing is output.  The path of the cvs is already in the PATH :C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\;  When typing "C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\cvs" there are outputs there.  But when other .exe e.g. calc is typed the corresponding program can be executed.  Any idea?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you say, "nothing is output"?

Comment: normally the DOS shall output "usage: cvs [cvs-options] command..."

Comment: So you are currently seeing "... is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Comment: @Tung No, Nothing is output
However under C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT typing cvs produces the expected output

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like a strange suggestion, but try `cvs.exe` instead of just `cvs`.  Without specifying an extension, your operating system will search for the first file that matches the name, `cvs`.  If it happens to find `cvs.bat` in one of your paths, then it will execute the .bat file instead of the.exe.

If you have cvs.bat , cvs.com, and cvs.exe within the same directory. The order of precedence would be the following:

1. cvs.com
2. cvs.bat
3. cvs.exe

I have a strong suspicion that there's a blank cvs.bat file hidden somewhere in one of folders defined in your path variable, and that you are actually running this batch file when you type `cvs`.

Comment: Thanks. your suspicion is correct. There are 2 cvs.exe which are components of another software but their path position is ahead of C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\ so one of the unexpected cvs is executed. Now it works after modifying the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

HI the answer is Run the exe with full path like "C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\cvs.exe" followed by CVS arguments like -q Checkout.....